# ECONNRESET Error while using electron-packager

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

The following error is showing up when i am using electron-packager to pack the application for windows.

```
 read ECONNRESET
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno 1
 npm ERR! u2_projector@1.0.0 package-win: `electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=public/icons/ms-icon-150x150.png --prune=false --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="Projector Controller"`  
 npm ERR! Exit status 1
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the u2_projector@1.0.0 package-win script.
 npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

The command i ran is as follows:

```
"package-win": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=public/icons/ms-icon-150x150.png --prune=false --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"Projector Controller\"",
```

My error log as follows

```
 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
 1 verbose cli [
 1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
 1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
 1 verbose cli   'run',
 1 verbose cli   'package-win'
 1 verbose cli ]
 2 info using npm@6.14.7
 3 info using node@v14.8.0
 4 verbose run-script [ 'prepackage-win', 'package-win', 'postpackage-win' ]
 5 info lifecycle u2_projector@1.0.0~prepackage-win: u2_projector@1.0.0
 6 info lifecycle u2_projector@1.0.0~package-win: u2_projector@1.0.0
 7 verbose lifecycle u2_projector@1.0.0~package-win: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
 8 verbose lifecycle u2_projector@1.0.0~package-win: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\pme\U2Scanner-ProjectorController\node_modules\.bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Vidhyanand\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\Vidhyanand\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Vidhyanand\AppData\Roaming\npm
 9 verbose lifecycle u2_projector@1.0.0~package-win: CWD: D:\pme\U2Scanner-ProjectorController
 10 silly lifecycle u2_projector@1.0.0~package-win: Args: [
 10 silly lifecycle   '/d /s /c',
 10 silly lifecycle   'electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=public/icons/ms-icon-150x150.png --prune=false --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="Projector Controller"'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle u2_projector@1.0.0~package-win: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle u2_projector@1.0.0~package-win: Failed to exec package-win script
13 verbose stack Error: u2_projector@1.0.0 package-win: `electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=public/icons/ms-icon-150x150.png --prune=false --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="Projector Controller"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
 13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
 13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
 14 verbose pkgid u2_projector@1.0.0
 15 verbose cwd D:\pme\U2Scanner-ProjectorController
 16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
 17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "package-win"
 18 verbose node v14.8.0
 19 verbose npm  v6.14.7
 20 error code ELIFECYCLE
 21 error errno 1
 22 error u2_projector@1.0.0 package-win: `electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=public/icons/ms-icon-150x150.png --prune=false --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName="Projector Controller"`
 22 error Exit status 1
 23 error Failed at the u2_projector@1.0.0 package-win script.
 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Packaging will reach 6% and then show the error.